# SQLite - WHERE Clause & UDFs

Tags: sql, sqlite, user-defined-functions

## Intro

I have the following SQLite table with 198,305 geocoded portuguese postal codes:

```
CREATE TABLE "pt_postal" (
  "code" text NOT NULL,
  "geo_latitude" real(9,6) NULL,
  "geo_longitude" real(9,6) NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "pt_postal_code" ON "pt_postal" ("code");
CREATE INDEX "coordinates" ON "pt_postal" ("geo_latitude", "geo_longitude");
```

I also have the following user defined function in PHP that returns the distance between two coordinates:

```
$db->sqliteCreateFunction('geo', function ()
{
    if (count($data = func_get_args()) < 4)
    {
        $data = explode(',', implode(',', $data));
    }

    if (count($data = array_map('deg2rad', array_filter($data, 'is_numeric'))) == 4)
    {
        return round(6378.14 * acos(sin($data[0]) * sin($data[2]) + cos($data[0]) * cos($data[2]) * cos($data[1] - $data[3])), 3);
    }

    return null;
});
```

Only **874** records have a distance from `38.73311, -9.138707` smaller or equal to 1 km.

---

## The Problem

The UDF is working flawlessly in SQL queries, but for some reason I cannot use it's return value in `WHERE` clauses - for instance, if I execute the query:

```
SELECT
    "code",
    geo(38.73311, -9.138707, "geo_latitude", "geo_longitude") AS "distance"
    FROM "pt_postal" WHERE 1 = 1
        AND "geo_latitude" BETWEEN 38.7241268076 AND 38.7420931924
        AND "geo_longitude" BETWEEN -9.15022289523 AND -9.12719110477
        AND "distance" <= 1
    ORDER BY "distance" ASC
LIMIT 2048;
```

It returns 1035 records ***ordered by `distance`*** in ~0.05 seconds, *however* the last record has a "distance" of `1.353` km (which is bigger than the 1 km I defined as the maximum in the last `WHERE`).

If I drop the following clauses:

```
AND "geo_latitude" BETWEEN 38.7241268076 AND 38.7420931924
AND "geo_longitude" BETWEEN -9.15022289523 AND -9.12719110477
```

Now the query takes nearly 6 seconds and returns 2048 records (my `LIMIT`) ordered by `distance`. It's supposed take this long, but it should only return the **874 records that have `"distance" <= 1`**.

The `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` for the original query returns:

```
SEARCH TABLE pt_postal USING INDEX coordinates (geo_latitude>? AND geo_latitude<?)
#(~7500 rows)
USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

And without the coordinate boundaries:

```
SCAN TABLE pt_postal
#(~500000 rows)
USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

---

## What I Would Like to Do

I think I know why this is happening, SQLite is doing:

1. use index `coordinates` to filter out the records outside of the boundaries in the `WHERE` clauses
2. filter those records by the `"distance" <= 1` `WHERE` clause, ***but `distance` is still `NULL => 0`***!
3. populate "code" and "distance" (by calling the UDF for the first time)
4. order by the "distance" (which is populated by now)
5. limit the records

What I would like SQLite to do:

1. use index `coordinates` to filter out the records outside of the boundaries in the `WHERE` clauses
2. for those records, populate `code` and `distance` by calling the UDF
3. filter the records by the `"distance" <= 1` `WHERE` clause
4. order by the "distance" (without calling the UDF again)
5. limit the records

**Can anyone explain how I can make SQLite behave (if it's even possible) the way I want it to?**

---

## Postscript

Just out of curiosity, I tried to benchmark how much slower calling the UDF twice would be:

```
SELECT
    "code",
    geo(38.73311, -9.138707, "geo_latitude", "geo_longitude") AS "distance"
    FROM "pt_postal" WHERE 1 = 1
        AND "geo_latitude" BETWEEN 38.7241268076 AND 38.7420931924
        AND "geo_longitude" BETWEEN -9.15022289523 AND -9.12719110477
        AND geo(38.73311, -9.138707, "geo_latitude", "geo_longitude") <= 1
    ORDER BY "distance" ASC
LIMIT 2048;
```

To my surprise, it still runs in the same ~0.06 seconds - and it still (wrongly!) returns the 1035 records.

Seems like the second `geo()` call is not even being evaluated... But [it should](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), right?

Comment: Please pick one wrong record, and check whether you still get the same result when you use its values directly: `SELECT geo(1.2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8);`

Comment: @CL. `[geo(1.2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8)] => 691.995`. As I was changing the code, I noticed that I was outputting one query with the arguments via `sprintf()` and I was executing another prepared query with PDO. The problem was, I wasn't passing the bound parameter to the prepared one! :S I'm so embarrassed right now, I was messing with this for hours and I couldn't spot it before. So sorry for your wasted time, at least you lead me to the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I was using `sprintf()` to see what kind of bounding coordinates where being computed, and since I couldn't run the query on any place other than PHP (because of the UDF) I was generating another query with prepared statements. The problem was, I wasn't generating the last bound parameter (the kilometers in the `distance <= ?` clause) and I was fooled by my `sprintf()` version.

Guess I shouldn't try to code when I'm sleepy. I'm truly sorry for your wasted time, and thank you all!

---

Just for the sake of completeness, the following returns (correctly!) 873 records, in ~ 0.04 seconds:

```
SELECT "code",
    geo(38.73311, -9.138707, "geo_latitude", "geo_longitude") AS "distance"
    FROM "pt_postal" WHERE 1 = 1
        AND "geo_latitude" BETWEEN 38.7241268076 AND 38.7420931924
        AND "geo_longitude" BETWEEN -9.15022289523 AND -9.12719110477
        AND "distance" <= 1
    ORDER BY "distance" ASC
LIMIT 2048;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query (*provided by [@OMGPonies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099140/89771)*):

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            "code",
            geo(38.73311, -9.138707, "geo_latitude", "geo_longitude") AS "distance"
            FROM "pt_postal" WHERE 1 = 1
                AND "geo_latitude" BETWEEN 38.7241268076 AND 38.7420931924
                AND "geo_longitude" BETWEEN -9.15022289523 AND -9.12719110477
    )
        WHERE "distance" <= 1
    ORDER BY "distance" ASC
LIMIT 2048;
```

Correctly returns the 873 records, ordered by `distance` in ~0.07 seconds.

However, I'm still wondering why SQLite doesn't evaluate `geo()` in the `WHERE` clause, [like MySQL](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL#page=15)...

Comment: I just deleted my answer, as I see it's the same as this one. Why was this answer posted by you, and not by OMGPonies?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall': It's from another question I asked ages ago (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2099140/89771), but that question is poorer and I was making a huge confusion with `HAVING` clauses at the time and that created a lot of noise. Thought it would be more appropriate to post another question than to resurrect a confusing one.

Answer (score 0):

This also return 873 records, ordered by `distance` in ~0.04 seconds:

```
SELECT
    "code",
    geo(38.73311, -9.138707, "geo_latitude", "geo_longitude") AS "distance"
    FROM "pt_postal" WHERE 1 = 1
        AND "geo_latitude" BETWEEN 38.7241268076 AND 38.7420931924
        AND "geo_longitude" BETWEEN -9.15022289523 AND -9.12719110477
    GROUP BY "code"
        HAVING "distance" <= 1
    ORDER BY "distance" ASC
LIMIT 2048;
```

The reason [this page](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL#page=15) doesn't have a `GROUP BY` clause is [MySQL specific](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> A HAVING clause can **refer to any column or alias named in a
>   select_expr in the SELECT list** or in outer subqueries, and to
>   aggregate functions. However, the SQL standard requires that HAVING
>   must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in
>   aggregate functions. To accommodate both standard SQL and the
>   MySQL-specific behavior of being able to refer columns in the SELECT
>   list, MySQL 5.0.2 and up permit HAVING to refer to columns in the
>   SELECT list, columns in the GROUP BY clause, columns in outer
>   subqueries, and to aggregate functions.

---

If no primary / unique key is available, the following hack also works (albeit a bit slower - ~0.16 seconds):

```
SELECT
    "code",
    geo(38.73311, -9.138707, "geo_latitude", "geo_longitude") AS "distance"
    FROM "pt_postal" WHERE 1 = 1
        AND "geo_latitude" BETWEEN 38.7241268076 AND 38.7420931924
        AND "geo_longitude" BETWEEN -9.15022289523 AND -9.12719110477
    GROUP BY _ROWID_
        HAVING "distance" <= 1
    ORDER BY "distance" ASC
LIMIT 2048;
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell [from the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.sqlitecreatefunction.php) whether or not `sqliteCreateFunction` defines an aggregate, like `SUM`, or a scalar, like `sqrt`.  Aggregate functions cannot be referenced in a `WHERE` clause; `HAVING` is required.

Per the SQLite [UDF documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html), you need to know if only **xFunc** is populated, or if **xStep** and **xFinal** are.  Those are the pointers SQLite uses to know the kind of function you're defining, and thus whether or not to honor it in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Aggregate UDFs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.sqlitecreateaggregate.php are here. I'm creating a regular UDF - like `LENGTH`, or `MD5`.

Comment: Good, OK.  So you found a bug, either in POD's implementation or in SQLite.  For my money I'd bet on PHP.  I've written SQLite UDFs in C and not seen the problem you're reporting.